# Hibernate cascade update gives null pointer

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entity which works fine during hibernate insert.

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User extends PersistentObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1803375723276957167L;

    // commenting this association allows update to work successfully.
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private ContactInfo contactInfo;
    private String name;
}
```

Then, I tried to perform update on an entity that I believe it is detached and get null pointer exception during `cascadeOnUpdate`.

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityEntry.getLoadedValue(EntityEntry.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:724)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:712)
    at com.myapp.dao.GenericHibernateDAO.save(GenericHibernateDAO.java:279)
    at com.myapp.service.StaffInfoServiceImpl.storeInfo(StaffInfoServiceImpl.java:74)
    at com.myapp.service.StaffInfoServiceImpl.storeInfo(StaffInfoServiceImpl.java:1)
```

**UPDATE**

**ContactInfo.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
@DynamicUpdate
public class ContactInfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4485388013971134422L;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String currentCity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "current_country_id")
    private Country currentCountry;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "char(10)")
    private String currentPostCode;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String currentState;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String currentStreetOne;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String currentStreetThree;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String currentStreetTwo;

    @Column
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Column
    @Length(max = 20)
    private String fax;

    @Column
    @Length(max = 20)
    private String homePhone;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @Length(max = 20)
    private String mobilePhone;

    @Column
    @Length(max = 20)
    private String officePhone;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String permanentCity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "permanent_country_id")
    private Country permanentCountry;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "char(10)")
    private String permanentPostCode;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String permanentState;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String permanentStreetOne;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String permanentStreetThree;

    @Column
    @Length(min = 3, max = 50)
    private String permanentStreetTwo;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version = 0;   
}
```

My question is why during insert the exception is not thrown while during update it is ? What did I miss here ?

Comment: Please show us the `ContactInfo` class as well

Comment: Added `ContactInfo` as requested. Thanks

Comment: Is there anything relevant in `PersistentObject`?

Comment: Nope, it only contains `id` and `version`.

Comment: Guess: you performed an update ant the lazy-fetched ContactInfo was null? Have a look at the values of your object-to-save at `GenericHibernateDAO.java:279`.

Comment: yes ContactInfo was null during update. In fact, during insert ContactInfo was null too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5267) of hibernate, that was fixed in version `4.1.7`.
Temporary workaround for your version, use `session.merge` instead of `session.saveOrUpdate`.

Problem was fixed under this [task](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3795)

Answer (score 5):

I think this error is because of the `orphanRemoval = true` property in the `@OneToOne` association.

When you update the `User` with `null` reference to `ContactInfo`, the hibernate might be assuming that the `ContactInfo` reference was set to `null` and then it try to remove the object that '*was there(but never existed)*' because of the orphanRemoval semantic.

If my logic about this error is true, there is one bug in the hibernate. Maybe this is fixed in a newer version of hibernate.